# C# OpenGL cannot create a texture from DLL (Context sharing issue)

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, dll

I need to use both C# and C++ in my OpenGL project. Ideally, the entire project is written only in C# using **OpenTK** (OpenGL functions ported to C#), **GLFW.NET** (aka ported GLFW), and **GlmNet** (GLM).

There's only one tiny place where I have to dynamically create an **OpenGL texture using libraries that are only available for C++**. In idea, this is not supposed to be a problem:

(make a DLL and use it in C#)

```
//In C++, Create DLL API for C# to use:
extern "C" MYDLL_API unsigned int GenerateTexture();

//in C#, bind an existing DLL.
[DllImport("MYDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "GenerateTexture", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint GenerateTexture();
```

This function should generate texture inside, set its bitmap and properties, and then return the handle of this texture. Spoiler - it immediately fails:

```
//C++. inside of a function GenerateTexture:
//(by the way, if that's important, on the side of C++, i use 'glad')

unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
^^^ sets texture to 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
^^^ throws access violation exception
```

I have googled about this issue and apparently, it's because OpenGL context is absent.

I have Glfw and OpenGL contexts all successfully initialized in C#, all functions are usable and workable. DLL itself is perfectly callable and I can even debug it. And everything is happening in one single thread.

Then why I cannot create a texture from a DLL?

first thought: maybe context is not magically passed to the DLL?

I searched how to pass the OpenGL context to the DLL, but everybody says when DLL is used, it becomes a part of the project, therefore context is automatically applied. OpenGL context is theoretically present in DLL.

Who or what fools me then?

A little handy problem-localizing test for you guys:

```
//Let's try creating a texture in C# itself
//right in the place where DLL is called
uint texture = glGenTexture();
           ^^^ returns a workable identifier 1.

uint textureFromDLL = DLL.GenerateTexture();
                        ^^^ access violation.
```

So here it is apparent that the actual problem is that only this DLL is the one who cannot access OpenGL functions.

I have no idea what to think in this situation, maybe C#'s OpenTK and C++'s glad are wrapping different OpenGLs?:) it makes no sense to me. or, maybe people were wrong saying that openGL context is automatically present in DLL. In this case, my question is how can i transfer this almighty yet occult context to my pathetic DLL.

I tried to create and bind a texture in C#, and right after it, pass a handle to this texture to the DLL. but everything's futile, it throws access violation exception right on the next command where i call `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT).` so yet again it needs full context, not just a handle.

Yes, I could rearrange the function so that C++ part does only the thing that has nothing to do with OpenGL. But it stresses me that something doesn't work when it theoretically should, and I'm afraid i will have serious problems if i need more DLL functionality in the future.

If someone needs to know it, my DLL is right inside the project, in Debug and Release folders. I use Visual Studio, C++20 (latest), C# .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: At which point do you initialize glad in c++? Is this happening after the OpenGL context is bound to the current thread?

Comment: I don't really initialize anything in C++, for my case, glad is just an included header <glad/glad.h> which provides readable namings for constants and functions, like GL_REPEAT etc.  C++ role is to give a single function, that's it. Only C# is responsible for context creation, and it's done by GLFW.

Comment: The only responsibility of a dll is when i'm calling its function, and this is the only point in time for C++ code, I don't think there's anything to be pre-initialized in my C++DLL. But maybe I'm wrong, and this is exactly what I'm here for.

Comment: You need to call `gladLoadGLLoader` after the OpenGL context has been created, otherwise all OpenGL functions (actually function pointers) are not initialized. If you don't do that, that's probably the problem.

Comment: I am very grateful to you for your help! I don't think I could come to such an answer on my own. Now I guess that is really the reason. I will try it and then I will post a full-fledged answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

The answer. First theoretical part and below the actual steps to solve it.

I guess I'm not going to be the only person facing such an issue so this is a comprehensive answer for other people, based on my current experience.

**Within one thread, OpenGL context holds, even while calling DLL.**

Then why did access violation happen to me?

My assumption was that OpenGL function is being called, then inside, graphics driver tries to work on it and tries to access an existing OpenGL context in memory. If i didn't initialize OpenGL, it attempts to access memory that is not allocated, hence access violation exception occurs.

Well... The thing is... In reality, driver does not fail at all, because it's not even called!  **Turns out DLL was not even bound to the OpenGL functions to call them!**

Actually, the C# situation is no different. neither of the functions are defined by default, they need to be bound dynamically, and I have the needed call **`Import(Glfw.GetProcAddress);` in C# code**. Without it, C# throws NullReferenceException when i call any OpenGL function.

And C++'s 'glad' is the same. All of the functions are just declarations which are function pointers to the actual driver functions, they need to be dynamically connected. Without it, these functions are pointing to nowhere.

They point to nowhere, therefore access violation error occurs. Again, context is here, it keeps its existence in DLL. The only thing needed is to **make OpenGL function pointers valid in my C++ code too**.

Holy user with the name 'BDL' precisely mentioned this idea in the comments with a suggestion to use `gladLoadGLLoader` in C++ to initialize glad.

I searched for some information about this function and its usage seems a little tricky: I have to pass some GLADloadproc which i have access to only in C#. While searching for how to accomplish it, i found a neighbouring 'glad' function `gladLoadGL()` which doesn't require any parameters to be passed. For a simple case like mine, this function is enough to initialize everything. And this is it! The easy function which truly solved my problem.

### Actual Steps

If you have this exact situation where you want to occasionally access OpenGL functions from the DLL, just add a new function to your DLL, call it something like "Initialize":

```
//C++
void Initialize() {
    gladLoadGL();
}
```

while in C#: (i guess it can be any other language, like Java, why not)

```
//right after you have initialized everything in C#
DLL.Initialize(); //initialize C++ part too.
```

You call it once. After it DLL is perfectly workable. Now everything is initialized in C# and everything is initialized in C++ codebase too. After this, you will be able to use OpenGL functions freely throughout the program and its DLL-s.

If that doesn't work, then I sincerely apologize for taking your time, it means the issue is yet again caused by something different.